# Keep Android app alive for a while

Tags: android, keep-alive

I need to keep my app alive for a while (5 minutes for example) also when the app is put in background.

This is why Android 7 kills my app in few seconds.

Keep in mind that I can't restart the main activity with a "startActivity(...)"
How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Your code that needs to be "alive for a while" should be in a `Service`. Particularly for Android 8.0 and newer, that will need to be a foreground service to be able to run for over a minute.